# Older Xamarin Android project won't build after updating Google Play Service packages. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android

After updating my Nuget packages for Google play location services, I get the following when attempting to build:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/ItemListIntents

I've deleted the obj and bin folders, as suggested by other posts I've found, but this did not resolve the issue. Is anyone aware of anything else that can be attempted to resolve this issue?

Edit: I've reverted back to an older version of the project, attempted the upgrade again, removed the bin and obj folders, restarted VS, attempted a rebuild and the error persists.

Comment: Please try to delete bin and obj folders, then restart VS  and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue. I still get the same error.

Comment: Then could you please post a basic demo so  that we can test with it?

Comment: Unfortunately this issue is occurring in a proprietary software and I can't upload the code. Recreating the entire project for demo purposes would probably not create the same build issues. At this point, we're considering just creating an entirely new project and copying everything into it.